# How to embed multiple images in email HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, image, email, embed

I have a list of 15 .jpg images saved in one folder. I want all of them to be embedded in the body of an email. My first approach was to vertically stack them to one long image and embed the single image - but then the big picture seems to shrink in the generated email and it gets smaller, the more pictures I stack together.

I struggle to find a reproducible example where **multiple images** are embedded below each other in a mail such that each picture keeps the original size.

Comment: maybe you generated smaller image? Or simply `email readed` displays it this way but image is correct - and then problem is not email but `email readed`

Comment: Hi @furas. Not sure what you mean by "email readed". The 15 images could also change to 100. So it's rather the way to embed them properly which would solve the problem for me, I guess.

Comment: I mean `email reader` like Thunderbird, Outlook, Gmail in web browser, etc. And you have images embed in HTML then maybe you may have to set width, height in HTML tag.  But first I would download email with images and check if images are really in correct size. I don't know what code you used to generate email so I can't confirm you create it correctly - simply I don't trust the code which I can't see and test.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good post here: http://dogdogfish.com/python-2/emailing-multiple-inline-images-in-python/ and 95% is taken from their example. Thanks to the bloggers!
I updated the imports to Python 3.x and adjusted the code such that all images in a specific folder will get embedded

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import cgi
import uuid
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.header import Header
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import numpy as np

gmail_user = "my_email@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "pw"
final_path_current = "path/to/folder/with/images"
receive_mail = "friend_email@gmail.com"

def attach_image(img_dict):
    with open(img_dict['path'], 'rb') as file:
        msg_image = MIMEImage(file.read(), name=os.path.basename(img_dict['path']))
    msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(img_dict['cid']))
    return msg_image


def attach_file(filename):
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octect-stream')
    part.set_payload(open(filename, 'rb').read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(filename))
    return part


def generate_email(gmail_user, to_list, img_dict):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msg['Subject'] = Header(u'Subject', 'utf-8')
    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = ','.join(to_list)
    msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg_text = MIMEText(u'Image not working', 'plain', 'utf-8')
    msg_alternative.attach(msg_text)
    msg.attach(msg_alternative)
    msg_html = u'<h1>Below are the images</h1>'
    for img in img_dict:
        msg_html += u'<h3>'+img["title"][:-4]+'</h3><div dir="ltr">''<img src="cid:{cid}" alt="{alt}"><br></div>'.format(
            alt=cgi.escape(img['title'], quote=True), **img)
    msg_html = MIMEText(msg_html, 'html', 'utf-8')
    msg_alternative.attach(msg_html)
    for img in img_dict:
        msg.attach(attach_image(img))

    return msg


def send_email(msg, gmail_user, gmail_pwd, to_list):
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to_list, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.quit()


img_dict = []
all_files = [f for f in listdir(final_path_current) if isfile(join(final_path_current, f))]

for file in all_files:
        img_dict_single = dict(title=file, path=final_path_current+"/"+file, cid=str(uuid.uuid4()))
        img_dict.append(img_dict_single)

email_msg = generate_email(gmail_user, [receive_mail], img_dict=img_dict)
send_email(email_msg, gmail_user, gmail_pwd, [receive_mail])
```